# Why do people feed to crow during Sraddha?

Tags: rituals, sraddha

People do Sraddha for dead elders ( specially parents ). After finishing the pooja & giving dakshina to Bramhana the last step is to feed the crow.

So What is the importance to feed the crow for Sraddha vidhi?